# Recursive method - increment a a value on each call

Tags: javascript, recursion, svg

I have the following method - a recursive one used to generate a tree structure from a JSON Schema.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/xn37b92q/)

I want to keep the level and rank of each node of the tree. 
(Rank=horizontal rank, level=vertical rank(increment sequentially)) The purpose of the level and rank is to later draw the same structure in an svg.

The rank is obtained correctly, but the level is not updated when going out of a nested list. How to update the level correctly?

Is there any other way to draw this structure on svg without using rank and level?

```
function traverseJSONSchema1(root, rootname, resultpane, lev, rank) {

    if (root.type === "object") {
        var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
        if (rootname !== "") {
            listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
            rank++;
            lev++;
        }
        var newlist = listitem.append("ul");
        var items = root.properties; //select PROPERTIES
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(items).length; i++) {   //traverse through each PROPERTY of the object
            var itemname = Object.keys(items)[i];
            var item = items[itemname];
            traverseJSONSchema1(item, itemname, newlist, lev + i, rank);
        }
    } else if (root.type === "array") {
        var items = root.items; //select ITEMS
        var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
        if (rootname !== "") {
            listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "[" + items.type + "]" + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
            rank++;
            lev++;
        }

        traverseJSONSchema1(items, "", listitem, lev + 1, rank);  //recurse through the items of array
    } else if (["string", "integer", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(root.type) > -1) {    //when the type is a primitive
        var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
        if (rootname !== "") {
            listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
            rank++;
            lev++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have problems with rank or with level?

Comment: The level is the problem - the question is updated by correcting the mistake.

Comment: How about returning the level when reaching the last node of a branch? If I understand correctly, you'd need to pass the highest level back up to the predecessor(s) for this to work properly

Comment: And after corrections I don't understand problem. Currently level shows depth of tree and I think it's right.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell's idea was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Chris Satchell's idea, returning the level was the solution.

```js
var data = {
  "title": "person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "birthday": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street address": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "house number": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "lane": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "phone number": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "code": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "location",
          "code"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "nickname": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
};

var title = data.title || "Root";
var result = d3.select("#trial-container");
var result1 = d3.select("#input-structure");
traverseJSONSchema1(data, title, result1, 0, 0);





function traverseJSONSchema1(root, rootname, resultpane, lev, rank) {

  if (root.type === "object") {
    var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
    if (rootname !== "") {
      listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
      rank++;
      lev++;
    }
    var newlist = listitem.append("ul");
    var items = root.properties; //select PROPERTIES
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(items).length; i++) { //traverse through each PROPERTY of the object
      var itemname = Object.keys(items)[i];
      var item = items[itemname];
      lev = traverseJSONSchema1(item, itemname, newlist, lev, rank);
    }

  } else if (root.type === "array") {
    var items = root.items; //select ITEMS
    var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
    if (rootname !== "") {
      listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "[" + items.type + "]" + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
      rank++;
      lev++;
    }

    lev = traverseJSONSchema1(items, "", listitem, lev, rank); //recurse through the items of array
  } else if (["string", "integer", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(root.type) > -1) { //when the type is a primitive
    var listitem = resultpane.append("li");
    if (rootname !== "") {
      listitem.text(rootname + ":" + root.type + "-" + lev + "-" + rank);
      rank++;
      lev++;
    }
  }
  return lev;
}
```

```css
   .structure,
   .structure ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     text-indent: 5px;
   }
   
   li {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
     border-left: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
     width: max-content;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <ul id="input-structure" class="structure">
  </ul>
</div>
```